# How do I learn how to ask a properly formed question on SE when I have failed so many times?

Tags: discussion

??? Ironic that the tag I can use here is [Discussion] when my questions are wrong because they solicit discussion. I have said I would stop using SE several times, but I keep coming back because I don't know of anything better and I get bored and lonely.

Comment: We've previously discussed the issue with your posts on your [original meta question](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3596/how-to-introduce-a-useful-topic-that-is-not-already-here). Your understanding of SE's purpose and scope seems fundamentally flawed. We are not an entertainment center or social circle for hire.

Comment: Have you tried reddit?

Comment: @Lilienthal I was offering *my* services as entertainment and social companion. "*Be the change you wish to see in the world.*" That is all that I really know how to do. I guess I will look for other sites, but I know zero about that. My attempts on Meetup to create, co-lead or participate with in-person groups are not really taking off.

Answer (score 7):

That's the problem: you are asking because you are bored and lonely. That isn't what Stack Exchange is for; there are many other sites which would be a better fit if that's your motivation.

To ask a good question, ask one that can be answered directly, not one which requires discussion.

Since we are in the Workplace area, it should be a question specific to the workplace environment. Interpersonal issues, for example, are out of bounds unless the answer would be different in the workplace than elsewhere.

The best SE questions are ones which quickly draw useful, applicable answers, which are general enough that they are likely to be websearched for, and which elicit answers that will be useful to that person doing the search without requiring further discussion.

Note that the perfect SE question would immediately draw the perfect SE answer, with no discussiion. This is very incompatible with your desire to socialize.

If you don't have answerable questions, and aren't sufficiently entertained by trying to craft good answers (which is what most of us spend most of our time here doing), this really isn't going to be a comfortable place for you. No site can be all things to all people, and it sounds like what you most want just isn't what we offer.

May I suggest trying someplace like BoingBoing? They're all about discussion and debate for its own sake, and last I checked they were an interestingly informed and opinionated bunch. I left partly because they changed the UI in a way that made reaching conclusions harder; that might actually be better from your point of view.

Comment: I suggest playing Diablo 2, not only can you chat away, but you can then go chop each other up in Blood Moor with fancy effects. Something we're sadly missing here in SE

Comment: I really do like the "Great question - Great answer" concept, and I think I have sometimes given some good answers, and occasional good questions. But some SE sites seem much more focused than others. I wonder if there is anything other than Meetup for finding ways to meet in person? It is so scattered and uncoordinated.

Comment: Alternatives to meetup is ***wildly*** off topic here. Find another place, probably not on SE, to ask that question.